# How to pass array to class option of rails generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, generator, ruby-2.0, thor

I'm creating the following ruby class generator:

```
class Template < Rails::Generators::Base
  source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

  argument :name, type: 'string', required: true
  ...
  class_option :templates, type: 'array', default: [1, 2, 3, 4], aliases: '-t'

  private
  ...

end
```

In the rails console I tried:

```
rails generate template test -t=1 2 
rails generate template test -t 1 2 
rails generate template test -t 1,2
rails generate template test -t=1,2  
rails generate template test -t=[1,2]
rails generate template test -t [1,2]
```

but the generator is not working correctly. It seems that the input doesn't return an array, because the following private method is not working:

```
def should_be_template_rendered(param)
  options.templates.include? param
end
```

Where `param` is simply a number. The result is that none of the templates are rendered at all. I have checked the `Thor` documentations [here](http://textmate.rubyforge.org/thor/Thor/Base/ClassMethods.html) and [here](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/wiki), but was not able to find an example on how the array is passed as argument.

Answer (score 3):

The following work fine for me

```
rails generate template test -t=1 2 
rails generate template test -t 1 2
```

Just notice that the result is a **string array**:

```
options["templates"]
#=> ["1", "2"]
```